# How to use Measures in Calculated column Formula in PBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, measure

I'm trying to use a previous calculated Measure in a Calculated Column in PBI, but i get the error **"expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns"**, how can i fix this? this is my code

```
Critical_Detrended = 1*(1+[Trend])
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe SUMX or a iterator function cound be used? If you can outline your data a bit more in the question it may help

Answer (score 0):

Calculated columns are static. They are calculated once, when the data is loaded. Their values cannot change. Thus, you can't use something dynamic, like measures, because measures are responsive, they are re-computed when the user selects something, changes the value of a slicer, etc.

The solution in your case is to change your calculated column to be a measure too.

You could take a look for example at [Calculated columns and measures in DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/) article.

Answer (score 0):

While calculated columns are not responsive to any slicers or filters set on your report, you absolutely can use measures in a calculated column definition so long as you understand how the row context to filter [context transition](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/) works and don't expect the calculated column to be dynamically responsive.

That said, the error you are getting sounds like `[Trend]` may output different data types in different situations but a column can only be a single data type. A non-obvious case where this sort of thing happens is when a measure sometimes outputs an integer and other times outputs a decimal type. In a case like that, you can force it to return a decimal type by multiplying by `1.0` or adding `0.0` or similar manner of type coercion. In your case, changing one of the `1` to `1.0` *might* do the trick if that's indeed the problem.

Comment: Hi Alexis, i applied your suggestion, and that error disappear but when i try to put my new column in a table i only have "NaN"s, that could be again for the format or something else?

Comment: It's more likely that your measure isn't working as you expect it to in the row context of a calculated column.